# Webscraping links not the same as manual browsing

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have scraped a site for 840 urls...
When I rebuld the urls for more insformation, my python scraper does not porvide the same data as if I manually click on the links.

For example, when I visit this website, https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch

If I click on the first 'Details' in the list, it take to a page with more information.

The information that is given is a relative link showing '/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=254119896'

I've scraped the 'details' relative link and then rebuilt the link to match the absolute address.
this address becomes

https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=254119896

However when I do this and try to scrape, I get a total different set of data and it takes me to a general landing page.

https://salesweb.civilview.com/

I thought at first, I needed to use a headless browser to fix the problem, but now I am not sure.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

baseurl='https://salesweb.civilview.com'
link='/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=254119946'
url1=baseurl+link

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() 
driver.get(url1)  
html = driver.page_source
time.sleep(10) 
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, if you first interact with the website, you can access the others urls. Unfortunately I have no idea why it works:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://salesweb.civilview.com/")
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Atlantic County, NJ').click()
driver.get("https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=254119946")
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
```